# file didn't uploaded using html input type file

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload a file using HTML input type file, but it doesn't working. The file doesn't uploaded to the expected folder and database (i want to store the file name to the table). It gives me no error appear when I inspect from browser. When I click the "Upload" button, the url is like http://localhost/mywebsite/ajax/upload? , method GET, Status Code 200 OK. What did I do wrong?

I am using mac, xampp, phpmyadmin, chrome.

Here's my view :

```php
<form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/upload')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Upload
    </button>
</form>
```

The controller :

```php
function upload()
{
if (!empty($_FILES)) 
 {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.'));
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.'));
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $data = "admin".uniqid().$file_ext;
    $targetPath = getcwd() . '/kirim_undangan/';
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $data ;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

$data_user = array(
  'request_id'  => $request_id,
  'status'      => '1',
  'filename_admin' => $uploadedFileName,
);
$this->load->model('excel');
$this->excel->upload_excel($data_user);
 }  
}
```

The model :

```php
function upload_excel($allDataInSheet,$request_id)
{
  $regex = "~\d{5}~";
  array_shift($allDataInSheet);
  foreach ($allDataInSheet as $key)     
  {
     preg_match($regex, $key['B'], $result);       
     $data = array(
     'request_id'         =>   $request_id,
     'to_name'            =>   $key['A'],
     'to_phone'           =>   $key['C'],
     'to_address'         =>   $key['B'],
     'to_zipcode'         =>   $result[0], 
     'tariff'             =>   '0'
     );
  $this->db->insert('excel', $data);
  $this->db->update('request',$request_id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to add a name to the input

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/upload')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Upload
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: it gives me http://localhost/mywebsite/admin/upload?file=tes+upload.xlsx but the file didn't upload to the folder and database

Comment: sorry, forgot the method="post" in the form-tag

Comment: i did , but nothing change :(